# How I can return an array through valueOf method?

Tags: javascript

How I can return an array through valueOf method when I type plus before the function call ?

Example :

```js
function add(n){
  add.valueOf = ()=>{
    return n
  }
return n
}

console.log(+add([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: what is your expected result of it?

Comment: I want to pass quiz - https://www.codewars.com/kata/53072ed3f36d6211250002ad

Comment: just remove + sign

Comment: ImranGalib, Okey , but how I can return an array from curried function to pass the quiz - codewars.com/kata/53072ed3f36d6211250002ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a function with a closure over an object and the array and take a stack for the collected `invoke` parts.

With calling of `value` get the value.

```js
function lazyChain(array) {
    const 
        stack = [];
        chain = {
            invoke(...props) {
                stack.push(props);
                return chain;
            },
            value() {
                return stack.reduce((r, [fn, ...p]) => r[fn](...p), array);
            }
        };
    return chain;
}
    

let a = lazyChain([1,2,3])
            .invoke('map', x => x * 2)
            .invoke('reverse');

console.log(a.value()); [6, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The entire point of the `+` operator is that it converts a value to a number.

If you don't want a number, don't use the `+` operator!!

Comment: Okey , but how I can return an array from curried function to pass the quiz - https://www.codewars.com/kata/53072ed3f36d6211250002ad

Comment: just remove + sign